Simple example of AC for beginners
I want to have a very simple example of axiom of choice in action, where only AC works.
AC says:  For every $x$ which elements are non-empty and pairwise disjoint, there exists a set $y$ which has precisely one element of each element of $x$.
For instance when you have $x = \{\{a\},\{b,c\}\}$, then yes through AC exists a set that has only one element of each of the sets of $x$ (but it actually cannot be said which one, $\{a,b\}$ or $\{a,c\}$) but you get the same result with separation, even better because you will get a definite set like $\{a,c\}$.
So such an example seems not so good since it makes AC look redundant and useless. I came up with this one and I wanna know if it is working: we have a set $x$ with non-empty sets that are pairwise disjoint, but we do not know anything about the elements of these sets of $x$. So we cannot use the axiom of separation because we couldn‘t even formulate the rule to which to separate what elements from which elements. But AC guarantees us a set with exactly one element of the sets of $x$ as its elements.
If it is not working, what would be your choice of a baby example of AC, like the one you could give after introducing its definition to visualize it?

A classic would be "the product of a collection of non-empty sets is non-empty" (which is in fact equivalent to AC), and it's great propaganda for AC because the statement should obviously be true (right? ;)

I'm not sure how you define "baby" example, but a classic example of the necessity of AoC is in the construction of non-measurable sets. You could also reference basic results in algebra that require Zorn's lemma (e.g., every non-zero commutative unital ring has a maximal ideal), since it is equivalent to AoC.

A classic is: given an infinite collection of pairs of socks, you need AC to choose one sock from each pair.

@RobertIsrael That is implied by the axiom of finite choice which is weaker than full AC (I think).

@RobertIsrael unless they’re toe socks, which I believe Russell would classify as a shoe.

@RobertIsrael (errr… let’s say these toe socks have little grippy things on the bottom… I imagine a product like that exists.)

Your penultimate paragraph does work as an example - but it’s really just a restatement of AC itself.

I like the statement that every linear space has a basis, which is what makes the concept of dimensions of linear spaces work even when the spaces in question are not finite-dimensional. I’m not sure whether this counts as a baby example though…

I do not think the socks example works. Because with separation you just choose the first socks of the pair  - and voila you get your set of the set of paired socks with exactly one common sock. Therefore I like my example better but maybe someone could write something about non-measurable sets and AC because that sounds promising too. Maybe „baby example“ was a bad term. I wanna have an example to get the idea/intuition of AC that is not spoiled by the fact that you can get the same result with separation.

@Pippen the point of the socks is there is no “first sock”: the socks in a pair are indistinguishable, or at least there is no clear cut rule for distinguishing one from the other in a generic pair of socks. This is an example Bertrand Russell gave, and he contrasted this with choosing one from each of infinitely many pairs of shoes, which doesn’t require choice, since you could just use separation to choose the left shoe from each pair.

@Pippen a mathematical version of this that we can prove requires the axiom of choice (i.e. can’t be done in ZF) is if we want to choose exactly one from each pair of an infinite set of pairs of sets of real numbers. By contrast if we had pairs of real numbers instead, we could just choose the lesser of each pair (in the standard ordering of the reals), and avoid using AC.

FWIW, I found Russel’s example of shoes and socks to be not helpful when I was first learning set theory. Because in real life there’s no problem whatsoever with picking a sock— you just reach into your drawer and grab one.

@Pippen I mean, if you like your example, then there really isn’t much point to other examples, since your example is literally a restatement of AC itself. There’s really no way to get closer to AC than that. Though if you also like the example of non-measurable sets, a classical construction of one is a Vitali set. You can read about its construction and how it uses AC in the linked Wikipedia article.

@DavidGao Do you think my example works or should I put it as another question for further exploration?
As a reminder here the example, even more sharpened: x has 4 non-empty, disjunctive sets t1,t2,t3,t4 as elements but no further information about what is in there in those t-sets. We wanna have a set y which has exactly one element with every set t1, t2,t3,t4 in common. AC does it, but only AC or would there be an alternative way in ZF?

@Pippen As I said, your original example in your question works, since it’s literally just a restatement of AC itself. But this ”sharpened” example does not: as long as $x$ only has finitely many elements, AC is unnecessary. Pairing and Union already ensures such an $y$ exists. AC is only necessary when $x$ has infinitely many elements.

@David Gao So if an x exists but we do not know how many elements it has and what is in those elements then if by fact x only has finitely many element (which we do not know) then still y exists already by pairing and union?

@Pippen Without AC there’re two inequivalent definitions of “finite”, but assuming the more common of the two definitions, then yes, as long as you know $x$ is finite (without knowing precisely how many elements it has), then $y$ exists. You need more than just pairing and union in this case, but ZF still implies this without needing AC. (When I said pairing and union I meant the case where the number of elements of $x$ is known and is finite. Then just pairing and union (depending on the precise formulations of those axioms you might or might not need separation) imply the existence of $y$.)

After discussing it in the comments section, here is an example where only AC leads to a set that contains precisely one element of every element of a set.
Assume a set x that contains infinitely many disjunctive and non-empty sets insofar as no pattern exists about the elements in the sets to refer to them in a finite formula. So for instance if you flip a coin infinitely and randomly often, you get x = {{$T_1$},{$H_2$},{$H_3$}…} and if you want a set just with the flip outcomes you need AC.

You can get a set of flip outcomes ${{T_1},{T_2},{T_3},\dots}$. Like with the shoes, you can choose only the tails and ignore the heads.

I do not think so. I need a set that „mirrors“ exactly the set of flip outcomes. So if x = {{H1}, {T2}, {T3}, {T4}, {H5},…} then y = {H1, T2, T3, T4, H5,…}. You need AC, ZF doesn‘t get it done (as far as I understand it).

If my example with the flip coins does not work, I‘d give this following example, changing my answer for the benefit of truth: Let x be the set of all non-empty, disjoint subsets of the real numbers. Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (ZF) cannot guarantee the existence of a set that contains exactly one element from each of these subsets. Only the Axiom of Choice (AC) can ensure this. Is this correct?

Yes, it seems you need the axiom of choice to prove it. Although it might still be true whne $AC$ is false.

There are uncountably many real numbers and uncountably many open intervals. Let's prove, however, that if we have a collection of nonempty open intervals that are pairwise disjoint, then there can be only countably many intervals in that collection.
Consider the intersection of each open interval with the rational numbers (which is still nonempty by the density of the rationals, and of course the resulting sets are still pairwise disjoint).
By the axiom of choice, there exists a set that contains precisely one element from each of these sets. However, such a set is a subset of the rational numbers, and therefore it must be countable. Since the set is in one-to-one correspondence with the original collection, that collection must also have been countable to begin with.

You don't need AC here to choose construct a choice function on the non-empty sets of rationals. This is becuase $\mathbb Q$ can be well-ordered (as is it countable).
